# Formula for rotational work

Tags: rotational-dynamics, work, torque

I read online that rotational work is defined as
$$W =\int \tau \mathrm{d} \vartheta$$
which is not exactly the same as
$$W = \int \vec{F} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{r}$$
So i was wondering if it possible to give a little more general formula for rotational work that resembles the one with the dot product. If I consider a force not perpendicular to the axis of rotation, can I use the infinitesimal displacement vector $\mathrm{d} \vec{\vartheta}$ and write this?
$$\mathrm{d}\vec{r} = \mathrm{d}\vec{\vartheta} \times \vec{r}$$
Doing so would allow me to write
$$W = \int \vec{F} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{r} = \int \vec{F} \cdot (\mathrm{d}\vec{\vartheta} \times \vec{r}) = \int (\vec{r} \times \vec{F}) \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{\vartheta} = \int \vec{\tau}\cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{\vartheta}$$
and keep a perfect symmetry with the other definition of work. Where is my mistake?

Comment: What makes you think you made a mistake? Especially if you realize that ${\rm d}\vec{\vartheta} = \vec{\omega} {\rm d}t$ just as ${\rm d}\vec{r} = \vec{v} {\rm d}t$. In the end you have $W = \int P {\rm d}t$ where $P=\vec{F}\cdot\vec{v} = \vec{\tau} \cdot \vec{\omega}$ is power.

Comment: @ja72 Well, online I didn't found this formula, only the one without the dot product and I found it very strange because of the symmetry with the non rotational case, so I thought that there might be some mistake in my reasoning.

Comment: The key world here is symmetry. Actually it is called duality usually in rigid body mechanics.  There is something [intriguing in this symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/390753/392) between linear and rotational quantities. Some quantities in pairs represent [lines in space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/375222/392) (line of action, line of rotation, percussion axis) and the rules that govern them are identical. (See included link)

Comment: Also read [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/387263/392) on angular momentum, to see that geometry (and symmetry) in mechanics.

Comment: @ja72 Thank you for the answer and the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to derive 3D power, and then assert that work is the time integral of power.

Consider a moving rigid body, with a force $\boldsymbol{F}$ applied and a torque $\boldsymbol{\tau}_C$ applied at the center of mass. The body is instantaneously rotating about some point such that the velocity of the center of mass is $\boldsymbol{v}_C = \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{r}_C$. Additionally the equipollent torque at the rotation center is $\boldsymbol{\tau} = \boldsymbol{\tau}_C + \boldsymbol{r}_C \times \boldsymbol{F}$.

Let us look at power at the center of mass and at the center of rotation. The two should be identical because power should be coordinate invariant.

$$\require{cancel} \begin{aligned} 
  P & =  \boldsymbol{F} \cdot \boldsymbol{v}_C + \boldsymbol{\tau}_C \cdot \boldsymbol{\omega} & &\mbox{at center of mass} \\ \hline
  P & =\boldsymbol{F} \cdot \cancelto{0}{\boldsymbol{v}} + \boldsymbol{\tau} \cdot \boldsymbol{\omega}=(\boldsymbol{\tau}_C + \boldsymbol{r}_C \times \boldsymbol{F}) \cdot \boldsymbol{\omega} & &\mbox{at rotation center} \\
 & =(\boldsymbol{r}_C \times \boldsymbol{\omega}) \cdot \boldsymbol{F} + \boldsymbol{\tau}_C \cdot \boldsymbol{\omega} = \boldsymbol{F} \cdot \boldsymbol{v}_C + \boldsymbol{\tau}_C \cdot \boldsymbol{\omega} & &\checkmark
\end{aligned} $$

So the rule for power (and hence work) is:

*At any arbitrary location **A**, dot product the force with the linear velocity and the torque with rotational velocity to calculate power. Work is the time integral of power.*

$$ P =  \boldsymbol{F} \cdot \boldsymbol{v}_A + \boldsymbol{\tau}_A \cdot \boldsymbol{\omega} $$
 $$ W = \int P {\rm d}t $$

Pick the center of rotation and $\boldsymbol{v}_A \rightarrow 0 $, or the line of action of the force and $\boldsymbol{\tau}_A \rightarrow 0$ and the above simplifies to just one inner product.